# Convert video from Hi8-Lp format

Tags: audio, video, encoding, decoding

Some video, was recorded by camera (Hi8-Lp format). Then it was decoded to mpeg2video codec. I have this decoded video. But decoded video have not correct video and audio speed (like fast playback) and have longitudinal lines on video (you can see sample).

[sample video](http://youtu.be/t3FSu_pzXR4)

**How to convert video with correct speed?**

Thx for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this application **"DVDSanta"** ..

http://www.topvideopro.com/burn-dvd/8mm-to-dvd.htm

I hope this answer help you...

Answer (score 0):

Use WinDV if You are on windows, then convert it with [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) (or [StaxRip](http://staxmedia.sourceforge.net/), [MeGUI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/megui/), [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/)) to Your preferable format.

On Mac You could use iMovie

On Linux You could use [xawtv](http://git.linuxtv.org/xawtv4.git) (didn't tried this one)

**Do not encode video when transferring from camera, do it afterwards**